# Why is this wrong? Normalising constant by Monte Carlo integration.

Tags: statistics, bayesian, monte-carlo

I have confused myself with probabilities and could really use someone to point out where I went wrong, because I don't think my result can be correct!

Here is my train of thought:

---

Bayes' rule is:

$p(\theta | y) =  \frac{p(\theta) p(y|\theta)}{p(y)}$

Now the usual reason people say this is hard is because we don't know $p(y)$. We can write:

$p(y) = \int p(\theta, y) d\theta$

Which is just using marginalisation.

Then:

$p(y) = \int p(\theta, y)d\theta = \int p(\theta) p(y|\theta)d\theta = \mathbb{E}_{\theta \sim p(\theta)}p(y|\theta)$

And then we just do Monte Carlo integration:

$p(y) = \mathbb{E}_{\theta \sim p(\theta)}p(y|\theta) \approx \frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^{N}p(y|\theta_n)$

with $\theta_n$ drawn from $p(\theta)$.

---

If this is all correct, can't we just easily compute the normalising constant using Monte Carlo integration by drawing samples from the prior and calculating their likelihood? Where am I going wrong here? Does it converge very slowly, or is there a fundamental flaw in my derivation (maybe with my expectation values?)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are indeed right; what you exhibit there is the basis of many Monte Carlo methods. For instance, in [importance sampling](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Importance_sampling), the importance weights are used to compensate for the unknown normalizing constant.

In particular, what you show there is *exactly* what is used in [particle Markov chain Monte-Carlo methods](https://www.google.com/url?q=https://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/~doucet/andrieu_doucet_holenstein_PMCMC.pdf&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwiv6KX91sXiAhVxpYsKHTqiB0kQFjACegQICBAB&usg=AOvVaw2AkPSV0Jl7X4ky6zzi-3OF) to compute the normalization constant (the marginal likelihood) using particle filters.